# jQuery autocomplete for all place names in the UK

Tags: javascript, performance, jquery, form, autocomplete

I made an autocomplete input box of every town, city and village in the UK. Yes, every single one. The load times are painful so is there a way to reduce that?

**Here is a sample:**

```
<input type="text" id="location" name="locations" placeholder="Edinburgh, Belfast, Cardiff, London">
$( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "Abberton",
      "Abbeytown",
      "Abbots Bromley",
      "Abbots Leigh",
      "Abbotsbury",
      "Abbotskerswell",
      "Abbotsley"
    ];
$("#location").autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
});
});
```

Here is a [JSFiddle with the entire list](https://jsfiddle.net/tft0fwbd/), which has 7726 items.

Comment: I think you should post it in stackoverflow, because you are seeking for hekp and not Code review...

Comment: Yeah you could be right, I had assumed because it works as intended it wouldn't the correct place for it, I thought it might be a performance issue that could be improved upon

Comment: On an aside, the edits made, helpedme understand how to ask a question in a more cohesive manner, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can improve performance by using `autocomplete` function with this options:

```
$( "#location" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags,
      delay: 0,
      minLength: 2,
});
```

This library has  a 300 ms delay by default. So setting `delay` to 0 disables it.
`minLength` is for loading the matches after the users typed at least 2 chars, I don't think there is a point to load them when you have only 1 character.

Good luck

Comment: Very good answer

Comment: I don't agree with removing the delay (also known as [debounce](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing/)). It helps skip searches when you quickly type in more letters, which improve performance. If performance is the main focus, you should keep it.

Comment: At least, it can be decreased I think.